# using POSIT algorithm in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'm practising POSIT algorithm in OpenCV, following the tutorial http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Posit

My goal is to estimate the pose of a 3D object and especially solve the unknown depth problem. In this tutorial, it is a cube side of which is 10mm.

part of the code:

```
std::vector<CvPoint2D32f> projectedPoints;
...
CvMat poseMatrix = cvMat( 4, 4, CV_32F, pose );  // pose moves object coord. to camera coord.
for ( size_t  p=0; p<modelPoints.size(); p++ )
{
    float modelPoint[] =  { modelPoints[p].x, modelPoints[p].y, modelPoints[p].z, 1.0f };
    CvMat modelPointMatrix = cvMat( 4, 1, CV_32F, modelPoint );
    float point3D[4];
    CvMat point3DMatrix = cvMat( 4, 1, CV_32F, point3D )
    //Transform the points from model space coordinates to camera space
    //The pose must be transposed because is in OpenGL format
    cvGEMM( &poseMatrix, &modelPointMatrix, 1.0, NULL, 0.0, &point3DMatrix, CV_GEMM_A_T );
    //Project the transformed 3D points
    CvPoint2D32f point2D = cvPoint2D32f( 0.0, 0.0 );
    if ( point3D[2] != 0 )
    {
            point2D.x = cvmGet( intrinsics, 0, 0 ) * point3D[0] / point3D[2]; // this is fx * X/Z
            point2D.y = cvmGet( intrinsics, 1, 1 ) * point3D[1] / point3D[2]; // this is fy * Y/Z
    }
    projectedPoints.push_back( point2D );
}
```

According to the equation, Z is already known. How can POSIT solve unknown depth? or solved in this tutorial?

Any idea, please!

Comment: there are other confusing points in this demo: + 'pose' matrix is unknown. Actually, it is the goal of the whole calculation.  Second, in cvGEMM, 'NULL' means there is no translation between object coord. and camera coord. which is rarely be a real scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cvPOSIT estimates the translation (X,Y,Z) and rotation vectors between the camera's and model's coordinates systems. The code you posted calculates the projections of the model points using a pose matrix. In the tutorial, that function is used with the real pose of the model (unknown in a real scenario) and the pose estimated by POSIT in order to compare both projections.
cvGEMS performs the points transformation( R*p + T ) in just one matrix multiplication. Note that the model points p have 4 coordinates(x,y,z,1).

Comment: thanks! I've got it. I'm moving on to some other tests with POSIT func

Comment: Thank you! I think I've finished testing cvPOSIT. Its estimation really works :)